# Rename a group of files to a string that exists inside each one

Tags: awk, xargs, mv, jq

I have a group of json files.  Each file contains one json object and they all have the same schema.  There is a field in the json that I want to rename the file to.  How can I do that?

I came up with this solution:

```
find . -name '*.json' | xargs -i mv {} $(cat {} | jq '.billingAccountList[0]' | tr -d \").json
```

But it doesn't work, because `cat` is trying to interpret the {}.  I was hoping the xargs would interpret it instead.  It gives me this error:

```
cat: {}: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop to handle the files one by one.

For instance, with `while read`:

```
find . -name '*.json' | while read fname; do
    newname=$(jq -r '.billingAccountList[0]' "${fname}").json
    mv "${fname}" "${newname}"
done
```

Using `for` might be possible, but it's more sensitive to spaces in the names of the files:

```
for fname in $(find . -name '*.json'); do
    ... (same as above) ...
```

Also note that you're moving the files into the *current* directory, as the original path is being stripped, so if you want to keep the directory structure:

```
find . -name '*.json' | while read fname; do
    fdir=$(dirname "${fname}")
    newname=$(jq -r '.billingAccountList[0]' "${fname}").json
    mv "${fname}" "${fdir}/${newname}"
done
```

**UPDATE**: Using `jq -r` as suggested by @steeldriver. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `jq -r` to output raw (unquoted) strings - rather than stripping quotes with `tr`

Also I'm going to assume that you want to rename the files relative to their parent directory (so, for example, if the value `.billingAccountList[0]` in `path/to/file.json` is `foo`, then the new name should be `path/to/foo.json` rather than `foo.json`), and that your implementation of `find` has a `-execdir`

So I'd do something like

```
find . -name '*.json' -execdir sh -c '
  echo mv -- "$1" "$(jq -r ".billingAccountList[0]" < "$1").json"
' find-sh {} \;
```

or (at least with GNU `find`) more efficiently

```
find . -name '*.json' -execdir sh -c '
  for f; do echo mv "$f" "$(jq -r ".billingAccountList[0]" < "$f").json"; done
' find-sh {} +
```

Remove the `echo` once you are satisfied that it's doing the right thing.

Comment: This looks interesting.  Why do you need the -- there and what's the `find-sh` for?

Comment: @DanielKaplan actually with hindsight you probably don't need the `--`, it's just to prevent `mv` from treating the filename as an option if it should happen to start with a hyphen - but I was forgetting that `find -execdir` will prefix the found files with `./` anyway. `find-sh` is just an arbitrary string passed as the shell's `$0` positional parameter, so that for example error messages from the shell command are easier to attribute. (Probably a more useful thing to add to the `mv` in place of `--` would be `-n` or `--no-clobber` to prevent accidental overwriting of an existing file.)

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`'s `zmv` (for better handling of conflicts):

```
autoload zmv
zmv -n '(**/)*.json(#qD.)' '$1$(jq -r '.billingAccountList[0]' < $f).json
```

(remove `-n` when happy).